# Which one is correct in the following sentences?

Tags: grammaticality

1. Belgium is considered to be a country of chocolate.
2. Belgium is considered to as a country of chocolate.

Comment: *Considered to as* is ungrammatical. However, even the first sentence sounds odd—as if you're saying Belgium is a country made of chocolate. More natural is *Belgium is a country known for its chocolate.*

Comment: It depends on the question it’s answering.

Comment: Generally, though, in sentences of this kind it's **considered to be** or **considered as**.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first one is grammatically correct.

There's an example from Oxford Dictionary
(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consider):

***CONSIDER***

Believe to be; think.

with object and infinitive

‘all three patients were considered to be in a critical condition’

According to  Reverso.context.net:

Unemployment is considered to be a national priority requiring carefully coordinated policies.

For the purposes of this study, all of the above-mentioned enterprises are considered to be part of the formal economy.